# Memory allocation

Tags: malloc

I have a base class and a derived class.
Things work well with this setup. I have added another class in base class, so its a nested class.
On allocation of memory for the new nested class, I see some memory corruption.
 I want to know when we have nested class, does the size of base class increase ?

Answer (score 1):

Odds are the changes are hiding an application code problem, just as certain memory bugs don't corrupt a running process the same way when run under a debugger, which also changes the environment.

`mallopt` is used to frob the value however, with this doc:

```
MALLOC_ARENA_SIZE
    The size of the arena, a chunk of memory that the memory allocator allocates
    and deallocates from the system. This value must be a multiple of 4 KB, and
    currently is limited to being less than 256 KB. Environment variable:
    MALLOC_ARENA_SIZE.
```

But like I said, if changes this *looks* like it fixes the corruption, don't believe it.  Better to set the arena size to whatever value exposes the application bug, then fix the bug itself.